# iPad 2 not updating to iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, icloud, ipad, software-update, error

Please don't scold me because I know I broke the cardinal rule of updating...never shut down in the middle of an update. I was updating to iOS 5.1 over the air on my iPad and after the update downloaded it went to the screen with the white apple and the loading bar. After 15 min nothing had loaded and I force shut it down. Now when I go to try and update it says "Install Now" because the download file is still in the iPad, I believe. I tap "Install Now" and it says "Unable to Install Update an error occurred installing iOS 5.1" every time. I tried installing it through iTunes and it said my iPad 2 was ineligible for this update. My iPad is still working, I can play games and what not, so it's not "broken"

I backed it up to iCloud prior to updating. Do you think I should restore and reload from iCloud or can you think of a way I could somehow update it again from my iPad?

Comment: I would give it some time, as the software was just released hours ago and the servers are getting hammered at this time. If you are still having trouble in 36 hours or so, then you could consider more drastic measures.

Comment: It does sound like your download got corrupted somehow - not positive it had to do with interrupting it though. Have you updated your iTunes to the latest version (released today)?

Comment: You should put the device into DFU mode, connect it to iTunes and then restore it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have it backed up. Restore it from the backup and then perform the update again. Following standard instructions for doing that.

Comment: I did update iTunes but that didn't work either. I think I'll wait the 36 hours, or tomorrow evening, and restore and reload then. I can't believe how stupid I was. Thank you guys for your answers though!